# Trying to create a symbolic link in OS 10.14.6

Tags: macos, command-line, symlink

I'm trying to install a symbolic link but when I enter the command I think should work ("sudo ln -s /Applications/harris/idl87/lib/xop/xop2.4/xop /usr/local/bin/xop"), I get no response at all. ????

Comment: Please clarify what you mean that you "get no response at all".  Is the "no response" before or after the sudo password prompt?  Also, there should be no output unless there's a problem

Comment: The sudo here isn’t going to help. Maybe paste the exact command and response or a screen shot of what you typed and what the result looks like?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Unix thing: no news is good news. The symbolic link is likely there. Try ls -l /usr/local/bin/xop and see if its there. The -l flag runs ls so that it draws an arrow back to what it links to.